# Redirect url after save or cancel form

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

In my new_form I tryed redirect to another page after press save or cancel button, but the attribute "RedirectUrl" don't work... (I remember that this worked perfectly in olds projects..)

my code:

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton2" RedirectUrl="URL_destino"/>
```

Some ideia to redirect url after save or cancel event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the URL, you need to add `Source`, so for instance:

```
https://<SPUrl>/sites/<siteUrl>/lists/<listName>/Forms/newForm.aspx?Source=<Redirect URL>

OR

https://<SPUrl>/sites/<siteUrl>/<documentLibraryName>/Forms/newForm.aspx?Source=<Redirect URL>
```

Please see the **alternate approach** at [Redirect Users to Thank You page from NewForm.aspx after form submission](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2011/05/redirect-to-another-page-after-new-item-submit.html).  The same will apply if cancelled.