# How to redirect user to the page where the file opened in SharePoint modern site

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site

I have an image webpart in one of the sitepage. The image is linked to open a pdf file and the link is as below format.

https://abc.sharepoint.com/:b:/r/sites/744/Shared Documents/24Jan2024.pdf?csf=1&web=1&e=fWYDb3

Above link I copied from through the triple dot of that document from the library.

Now when, user tries to click on the image, it successfully redirects the user to the file over the same tab in browser. Now when user tries to close the file from the cross icon available, it auto redirects to the library location where the document is present.

Client wants the user to auto redirect to the original page from where user has clicked the image.

So, is there any way we can specify the page URL over the file URL for this redirection to happen?
Please guide me here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think it is possible using SharePoint out of the box functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

See: [Redirect url after save or cancel form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/265227/redirect-url-after-save-or-cancel-form)

And: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/is-it-possible-to-navigate-back-to-sharepoints/0b5b2d26-c429-48e8-8bbd-67cf8d30971a

Try using `Source` in your URL: `...fWYDb3&Source=<URL>`